# Can an XSD file ensure that an attribute of an element that occurs an unbounded number of times is true exactly once?

Tags: xml, xsd

The XML I'm structuring can contain any number of "user" elements, and I want to ensure that an attribute called "isDefault" is set to true on exactly one of those users.

For example, something like this would be valid:

```
<users>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
    <user isDefault="true"/>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
</users>
```

However, this:

```
<users>
    <user isDefault="true"/>
    <user isDefault="true"/>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
</users>
```

And this:

```
<users>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
    <user isDefault="false"/>
</users>
```

Would be invalid. Can I achieve this using an XSD or do I need to validate it programmatically?

Comment: you should correct your question's title, it's very poorly written

Comment: @CreativeMind Sorry about that, ended up having to shorten the title to comply with character limit and obviously made a mistake along the way! The body of the post though I think was fairly clear in demonstrating what I was trying to get at.

Comment: See Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926987/xml-schema-only-one-element-should-have-attribute-set-to-true

Comment: You *can* achieve that in XSD if you use a parser which supports XSD 1.1. Then you can use `xs:assert` and test the contents of each attribute using XPath. If you can't use XSD 1.1, or an extension like Schematron, the best solution are the ones in the link that @MathGuy posted.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to solve this problem is to re-think the XML and specify that the default user is listed first, and the user listed first is the default user.  Then a change to the default user involves moving that user to the top of the list, instead of changing two `isDefault` values, and you are guaranteed without any further effort that there is always exactly one `user` element which is first.

Comment: I like this.  Or, along similar lines, have another honored place besides position one.  It might be a `users/@default` attribute that references the default user by name or id.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, @C.M. Sperberg-McQueer. The only downside is that this particular XML format will be viewed and manipulated primarily by users with very little knowledge of the language and, ideally, will allow them to make the changes they need without consulting documentation.

Comment: The attribute at the users level had occurred to me as well, @kjhughes, but then is there any way for me to validate that the provided value is actually listed among the child user elements?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to declare a key constraint on the user identifiers, and a keyref constraint on the default-user attribute.  Look for information on XSD identity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If the `isDefault` attribute has to always be present, you can't achieve this with XSD 1.0 alone.

With XSD 1.1 you could use an `<xs:assert>`:

```
<xs:element name="users">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="user" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(user[@isDefault='true']) = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```